# How to obtain the file location of a running Windows PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Years ago, I set up a PowerShell script in Windows 10 to automatically turn on NumLock whenever the PC started. Now, I have a better solution -- but cannot find the original script. Still, it activates whenever the PC is logged on, trying to turn on NumLock, quickly failing and instantly quitting.

Is it possible to locate the original file prompting PowerShell so I may disable it?

[image: Before error appears.]

[image: Error appears for two frames, before quitting.]

The shell closes instantly after the error appears, which reads

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\andre\Downloads\Programs\NumLockOn.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ &'C:\Users\andre\Downloads\Programs\NumLockOn.ps1'
+  ------------------------------------------------
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\andre\...s\NumLockOn.ps1:String) [],
    CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I assume that if you hit CTRL+C the shell closes?

Comment: The shell closes instantly after the error message appears.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/954950/run-a-script-on-start-up-on-windows-10 check this

Comment: Sadly, Deepaan, none of the methods linked was the one I seen to have used.

Comment: Have you checked the task scheduler?

Comment: Maybe use the basic version of [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/), set file name to `*.ps1`, containing text to `NumLockOn.ps1` and look in to C:\

Comment: Have you checked your GPO (domain/local), and logon scripts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Note the rule *DO NOT use images of code.*